# tbl_svysummary unexpected format for p_unweighted

Tags: survey, gtsummary

I would like to include weighted and unweighted n/N, and their respective proportions in a gtsummary table . According the help of gtsummary, both p and unweighted p will be formatted as percentage

See <https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_svysummary.html>

, but I was unable to obtain the "p unweighted" formatted as percentage.

This is the reprex using data from Academic Performance Dataset from survey package.

```
require(survey)
data(api)

dstrat <- svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc
                    ,variables = apistrat[,c('pcttest','growth','awards')])
dstrat <- svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc ,variables = apistrat[,c('pcttest','growth','awards')])

gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(data=dstrat ,type=list(pcttest~'continuous',growth~'continuous',awards~'categorical') ,statistic = list( all_continuous()~c("{mean} ({sd})")

                        ,all_categorical()~c("{n}/{N} ({p}%) ; {n_unweighted}/{N_unweighted} ({p_unweighted}%)")
                        
                      )

)
```

This is the table output.

[gtsummary table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niZBK.png)
Am I missing something?

Thank you.

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)

packageVersion('survey')
[1] ‘4.1.1’

packageVersion('gtsummary')
[1] ‘1.5.2’

Answer (score 0):

You've found a bug in the default behavior of the unweighted proportion. Thank you for reporting! You can follow this GitHub Issue to track the resolution https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1181

In the meantime, this code will get you nicely formatted tables.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

data(api, package = "survey")

dstrat <- 
  survey::svydesign(id = ~1, strata = ~stype, 
                    weights = ~pw, data = apistrat, fpc = ~fpc, 
                    variables = apistrat[, c("pcttest", "growth", "awards")])

gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(
  data = dstrat, 
  include = awards,
  type = awards ~ "categorical", 
  statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{n}/{N} ({p}%) ; {n_unweighted}/{N_unweighted} ({p_unweighted}%)",
  digits = all_categorical() ~ list(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, style_percent)
) %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 6,194** |
| --- | --- |
| awards |  |
| No | 2,236/6,194 (36%) ; 87/200 (44%) |
| Yes | 3,958/6,194 (64%) ; 113/200 (56%) |

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: A tiny bug in an incredibly useful package.
Thank you, Daniel.

Comment: Thanks Jesus! FYI, the dev version of the package on GitHub has been updated with this bug fix

Comment: Flawless! Thanks Daniel!